# Nodejs binary http stream

Tags: node.js, express, stream, binaryfiles

I need to stream files from a client (nodejs command line) and a server (express nodejs).

This is the client side:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

// ...

  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
  readStream.on('end', function() {
    that.emit('finished');
  });
  readStream.pipe(request.post(target));

// ...
```

This is the server side:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// ...

    app.post('/:filename', function(req, res) {
      req.setEncoding('binary');
      var filename = path.basename(req.params.filename);
      filename = path.resolve(destinationDir, filename);
      var dst = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
      req.pipe(dst);
      req.on('end', function() {
        res.send(200);
      });
    });

// ...
```

All is working, files are saved correctly on the server side... but **they are about 50% bigger than the source files**. I tried to see difference between the two files with `hexdump` and the server side file has similar content but with 0xC2 sometimes. I guess this is related to encoding.

Comment: Why do you set the encoding? This will [convert every single chunk into strings](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) and is mainly intended if you want to read strings from the stream. As you directly pipe the request to a file, I don't think you should be calling `setEncoding`.

Comment: try `fs.createWriteStream(filename, {encoding: 'binary'})`

Comment: `fs.createWriteStream(filename, {encoding: 'binary'})` didn't work. Node api: The encoding can be 'utf8', 'ascii', or 'base64'

Comment: Removing 'req.setEncoding('binary');`  is the solution. Strange... I added it when it wasn't working

Comment: Good to know! Will add this as an answer so that the solution will be easier to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `req.setEncoding('binary')`.

This will [convert every single chunk into strings](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) and is mainly intended if you want to read strings from the stream. As you directly pipe the request to a file, you don't need to do it.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning that `binary` encoding is deprecated.

Comment: This isn't mentioned in the documentation. The [source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.8/lib/_stream_readable.js#L195) mentions *backwards compatibility*, but not deprecation. Do you have a link?

Comment: Which refers to [this issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3279#issuecomment-11759502), looks like `binary` won't go away soon...

Comment: Well, I think one can tell that `binary` is a little deprecated, but not deprecated-deprecated) Anyway, it's not a good idea to use it in new code.